# rspec failed on show page which can be accessed without error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

Here is the rspec error message:

```
  5) CustomersController GET customer page 'show' should be successful
     Failure/Error: get 'show' , :id => customer.id
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/customers/show.html.erb:43:in `_app_views_customers_show_html_erb___16283441_33497004'
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

name is one column in customer model.

Error above caused by the spec code for customers controller:

```
it "'show' should be successful" do
  customer = Factory(:customer)
  get 'show' , :id => customer.id
  response.should be_success
end
```

The 'show' in customer controllers is :

```
  def show
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Any thoughts about the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error (`undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`) is coming from your show view, line 43.

```
     # ./app/views/customers/show.html.erb:43:in
```

and it's because you're calling `something.name` when `something` is `nil`.